# Select all the files with a spefic extension Github actions workflow

Tags: yaml, github-actions, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

Hi I am trying to run a pre-commit hook on all the files with .sql extension. I was wondering how can I do that. All those files with .sql are in the **models**/ directory, but I have sub-directories within that directory too (to group those sql files) so what is the best way to get all the files with .sql ending? . This is my `.pre-commit-config.yml` file:

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff
    rev: 0.9.1
    hooks:
      - id: sqlfluff-fix
        args:
          [
            --exclude-rules,
            'L011,L031',
            --dialect,
            'clickhouse',
            --templater,
            'dbt',
            --fix_even_unparsable,
            'True',
          ]
    files: '*.sql'
```

What should I assign to **`files: '*.sql':`** ^ instead of this

In the  pre-commit [documentation](https://pre-commit.com/), I couldn't find an answer or in the sqlfluff [documentation](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/cli.html#sqlfluff-fix)

Comment: Did you try [filtering with file types](https://pre-commit.com/#filtering-files-with-types) e..g `types: [file, sql]`? The extension `.sql` is supported with the `types` filter (https://github.com/pre-commit/identify/blob/fdab9f7afac7b70dd7eb30dd2eea7f7b688b0201/identify/extensions.py#L211).

Comment: @Azeem yeah thanks that works, how should I set it up so it will take all the sql files in the PR rather than entire branch

Comment: IIUC, you want to run it only on the files in the PR, right?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Right. Are you running `pre-commit` via its action (https://github.com/pre-commit/action)?

Comment: Yes I am using :pre-commit/action@v3.0.0

Comment: Should I be setting it up as:
  pre-commit run --hook-stage commit sqlfluff-fix --all-files ?

Comment: You can use `--from-ref` and `--to-ref` for this. See https://github.com/pre-commit/action/issues/7#issuecomment-1251300704 and https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-run.

Comment: @Azeem thank you ser you are a true gentelman. Lastly It does run the linter and shows me the fixed version of the sql file but then the workflow fails. is there a way to automatically apply those changes into that file?

Comment: You're welcome! :) For that, you'll have to use https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/cli.html#sqlfluff-fix, commit and push the updated files to PR.

Comment: Aah I see so I have manually commit and push, it cannot be done automatically in the Github actions

Comment: You can use https://github.com/stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [filter files by file types](https://pre-commit.com/#filtering-files-with-types) i.e. `types: [file, sql]` as SQL (`.sql`) filtering is supported by [`pre-commit`](https://github.com/pre-commit/identify/blob/fdab9f7afac7b70dd7eb30dd2eea7f7b688b0201/identify/extensions.py#L211).

To keep this restricted to a PR, you might want to use [`--from-ref` and `--to-ref`](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-run) as part of your workflow. Refer to this [comment](https://github.com/pre-commit/action/issues/7#issuecomment-1251300704) for an example:

```
--from-ref ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }}
--to-ref   ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
```

By default, `sqlfluff` will fail in case of any violations i.e. it'll return non-zero exit status resulting in step failure. This can be suppressed by using `--nofail` flag if required.

And, to apply the changes automatically, you'll have to update workflow as if you're running:

```bash
sqlfluff fix --force ...
```

`--force` is to skip the confirmation during fixing SQL issues.

After that, you can commit these changes via https://github.com/stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action or manually.

---

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in [anthony sottile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812183/anthony-sottile)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75674208/7670262), the filter is redundant as [`sqlfluff` already takes care of it](https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff/blob/33e4b121effbd73500386fa3408acd7d6b0a9cd2/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml#L6).

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! There aren't many resources available on sqlfluff with pre-commit hooks but you provided top notch solutions! I am truly GRATEFUL

Comment: I dodged the fails with continue-on-error: true step

Comment: @Dude: Glad I could be of help! :) Regarding `continue-on-error: true`, the step fails as soon as it encounters an error and doesn't execute the rest of the step. For your use case, it might be enough so it's all good. However, you can simply skip linting and directly run the fix command if that's what you want to do eventually.

Comment: `types: [file, sql]` is redundant -- `sql` is subset of `file` -- but also that doesn't need to be set at all (see my answer below)

Comment: @anthonysottile: Thank you for pointing that out! I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`files` is [a regex](https://pre-commit.com/#regular-expressions) and not a glob so `*.sql` is not the correct pattern for it -- the correct regex for that would be `files: \.sql$`

but, you shouldn't need to set `files` (or `types`) at all -- the point of including a pre-written remote repository is it is already set up out of the box for you!  for example, the remote `sqlfluff` repo [already sets `types: [sql]`](https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff/blob/33e4b121effbd73500386fa3408acd7d6b0a9cd2/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml#L6)

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Haha I actually watched one of your videos  on pre-commit in anthony explains just before I started working on this, cant believe you are here lol. Would love to see more episodes on these guys  ^^